# Can I merge stackoverflow accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I made a stackoverflow account associated with an OpenID last year, and posted a few things.  Recently I tried to log back in and had forgotten my password, so I've been posting as an unregistered user with a different email address.  Today I remembered the password for my actual account, and I was curious: can I merge the few posts I made as an unregistered user into my registered account?  It's not really a necessity, I just like having it all in one place.

Comment: To make sure a mod sees this, flag your post using "Requires moderator attention".

Comment: Looks like you have at least four unregistered accounts. I've merged them into your registered account.

Comment: There's another Mike Turley around which has a different email address. Is that also you? If so, can you temporarily switch your main account to use this other email as a way of verifying?