# How to log back into an unregistered account?

Tags: support, login, unregistered-users

I was unregistered, and asked a question. Then I decided to join using my OpenID.

I didn't register via the same computer as the unregistered though, so now it auto-logs me into my registered account, while my unregistered account is still active.

I want to accept an answer and leave comments under my unregistered account. How can I log back onto it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62544/can-i-merge-stackoverflow-accounts) you need to flag your post as needing moderator attention and ask for them to be merged.

Comment: Thanks, I asked all my accounts tied to my email to be merged.

Answer (score 11):

Community moderators can no longer merge user profiles, even unregistered ones.  See:

- [Allow community moderators to merge accounts where one is Unregistered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192725/158428)

Therefore Martin Smith's answer is no longer valid.  Instead one must use the **contact us** page
(link in footer, e.g.: https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact)
and fill out the form:

> [image]