# Why is accounts merging only possible by staff?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, merge-accounts, stack-exchange-team

To merge several accounts into single one the actions from staff side is needed. Regular user need to request it by contact page, moderators have another special page for this. But in both cases this work cannot be done without agree from staff.

What's the reason for such restrictions? Why don't allow moderators do this work?

Comment: This is addressed in the answer to [Allow community moderators to merge accounts where one is Unregistered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192725/allow-community-moderators-to-merge-accounts-where-one-is-unregistered). This used to be possible for moderators, but it was removed for the reasons in the answer there. The later move to universal login also made this impossible since accounts are now at the network level rather than at the site level as before.

Comment: Regular users actually can merge accounts together themselves if both are registered (unregistered accounts are ineligible for security reasons), they have access to the email addresses for both accounts (verify they own both), and the accounts don't have too much reputation (simple sanity check). Might be a couple other criteria I'm forgetting. But if eligible, it's an entirely automated system.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer but to my understanding @animuson is correct. But when systems can't automatically validate the merge, it becomes very risky and has many requirements and considerations to weigh. _Every_ error with the tool can cause propagate some very serious problems (though it's gotten safer). It's honestly just safer for everyone involved if we can look at and sign off on them when a user can't initiate it themself

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can answer this because it happened exactly at the time I was transitioning from a moderator to an employee, back in 2013.

Every effort was expended to allow moderators to keep this ability; the problem was that we felt that the *consequences* of getting it wrong were too much to ask of a volunteer, because it could mean inadvertently helping an account become compromised, or at the least exposing someone's private info to another. That's not something we were comfortable accidentally happening to users OR moderators.

This was *highly* compounded by the community's desire to use anonymous email services like Mailinator and others, which was a whole other nest of Rumpelstiltskin breaches waiting to happen, so there was quite a bit of urgency to rip out a ton of wiring anyway, which made making the tool employee-only make that much more sense.

It wasn't because mods weren't trusted, it was because the tools around it were so bad that it was irresponsible to even hand them to anyone any longer.

Comment: Could you please add examples of the mentioned concerns *"inadvertently helping an account become compromised, or at the least exposing someone's private info to another"*?

Comment: Any time you merge two accounts you essentially put them into a blender. All of the PII gets grouped together, so after one owner logs in,  they see the other account's credentials, email, etc in their account settings and history.

Comment: Interesting. I thought the merging means changing ownership for posts, comments, etc, but leave only userA credentials. What's the reason to share them for both users - A & B? How is it even possible to store both emails for single account?

Comment: People can have multiple credentials tied to their account. Back then, we supported *any* working OpenID endpoint, plus the SE OpenID (OpenID was a very interesting choice), plus work to eventually support oAuth. So each set of credentials has to point to the same site profiles.

Comment: So, your perception is correct! It's just that _all_ of the accounts merged together continued to "own" everything in the account, posts included, as well as access to remove or add additional ways to login. They remained separate ways to log in to the same central network profile which owned the rest of the site profiles. Look for Jeff's blog about the Costanza Wallet from around that time./